# SwiftUI, why is object nil in clousure

Tags: swiftui

Bellow is a simplification of my code, where the `FDocument` is a

```
class FDocument: NSObject, ObservableObject, Codable
```

When i hit the button, the `document` is assigned proper with a new instance and `isDocumentPresented` is changed, however in the

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isDocumentPresented)
```

the document is suddenly nil

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    @State var document: FDocument?
    @State var isDocumentPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
    
            Button("New") {
                
                document = FDocument()
                isDocumentPresented = true
                
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isDocumentPresented) {
            DocumentEditor(document: document!) // <- NIL HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variant with item instead, like

```
        Button("New") {
            
            document = FDocument()
        //    isDocumentPresented = true    // << not needed !!
        }
    }
    .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
    .fullScreenCover(item: $document) { item in   // << valid !!
        DocumentEditor(document: item)     // << here !!
    }
```

Comment: that works... but any idea why my approach didn't work?

Comment: `fullScreenCover(isPresented:` captures document on creation, which is nil (and closure is not updated `cause does not see dependency).

Comment: and what if i am dependent on two objects? not just 1 item for the fullScreenCover

Comment: That is different question, but finally it would end up with some variant with of single item representable, I think.